# WSO2 Identity Server: Searching user by their username api not working

Tags: postman, wso2-identity-server

Is there any API available to fetch the details of a user using their username only?

I've followed this https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/getUsersByPost

But it doesn't work

[image: see attached screenshot of postman requests]

Comment: What is the version of IS that you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The URL you were trying was wrong.

- SCIM v1 users endpoint: `https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users`
- SCIM v2 users endpoint: `https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users`

2. On the payload, you have mentioned scim v1 schema. Maybe you wanted to try the API in scim v1, but we recommend using V2.

Following are sample requests for your requirement in SCIM V2.

If you want to use `POST` request to `/Users/.search` endpoint:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users/.search' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:SearchRequest"
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "userName",
        "name"
    ],
    "filter": "userName eq userA",
    "domain": "PRIMARY",
    "startIndex": "1",
    "count": "10"
}'
```

If you want to use `GET` request to `/Users` endpoint:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users?startIndex=1&attributes=userName,Name&count=10&filter=username%20eq%20userA&' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
--data-raw ''
```